# How can I get id,class or name attr an element with jquery

Tags: jquery, attr, html

I'm new in jquery. How can I get name,ID or class name an element with jquery.I'm trying as;

```
<div class="className" onclick="getname();"></div>
<div id="idName" onclick="getName();"></div>
<div name="attrName" onclick="getName()"></div>

function getName(){
attrName = $(this).attr("name");
alert(attrName);
}
```

but doesn't work

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

**JavaScript**

```
$(function () {
    $('div').click(function () {
        var elem = $(this);
        alert('Class: ' + elem.attr('class'));
        alert('Id: ' + elem.attr('id'));
        alert('Name: ' + elem.attr('name'));    
    });​​​​
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="className" onclick="getname();"></div>
<div id="idName" onclick="getName();"></div>
<div name="attrName" onclick="getName()"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
​div {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}​
```

JSfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/54ynV/

In the script above we're attaching to the click event of every div on the page `$('div').click...`. In the callback we're getting it's attributes.

Answer (score 4):

Firstly using jQuery you should attach `click()` handlers rather than use antiquated `onclick` attributes. Then you can use the `this` keyword in the manner you have in your function.

Try this:

```
<div class="className"></div>
<div id="idName"></div>
<div name="attrName"></div>
```

```js
$(function() {
    $("div").click(function() {
        var name = this.name;
        var cls = this.className;
        var id= this.id;

        alert("Name: " + name + " / Class: " + cls + " / Id: " + id);
    });
});
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/tqxrV/)

The attributes you've selected are all available through POJS, you could also convert `this` to a jQuery object to get other attributes, for example:

```
var title = $(this).attr('title');
var myattribute = $(this).data('myattribute'); // using HTML5: <div data-myattribute="foo"></div>
```

Comment: Why are you redeclaring `var` three times (twice more than necessary), using `name` twice and not using `this.className`?

Comment: @DavidThomas Sorry, was busy making a fiddle to demonstrate. Errors fixed. I also used `attr()` to demonstrate, will make a note.

Comment: `this.name` is undefined, at least on Chrome; `this.getAttribute('name')` gives the expected value.

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass a reference to the element you want to get the name attribute of. Try this:

jQuery

```
function getName(me) {
    attrName = $(me).attr("name");
    alert(attrName);
}​
```

HTML

```
<div class="className" onclick="getname(this);">a</div>
<div id="idName" onclick="getName(this);">b</div>
<div name="attrName" onclick="getName(this)">c</div>​
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/zuYLs/)**

Now you should get the name of the last element since that's the only element that has a name. The others will return `undefined`.